# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.1.19 on django

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am new to this. I took the image of running django application and spawned the new vm that points to a different database but I am getting this "502 Bad Gateway  nginx/1.1.1"

when i tested this in development mode, it works fine but not otherwise.

i looked into /var/log/nginx/access.log and error.log but nothing found there.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would start to debug this by creating a simple django project and see if you can deploy it on that VM.

Answer (score 1):

Error **502 Bad Gateway** means that the NGINX server used to access your site couldn't communicate properly with the *upstream server* (your application server).

This can mean that either or both of your NGINX server and your Django Application server are configured incorrectly.

Double-check the configuration of your NGINX server to check it's proxying to the correct domain/address of your application server and that it is otherwise configured correctly.

If you're sure this isn't the issue then check the configuration of your application server. Are you able to connect directly to the application server's address? If you are able to log in to the server running the application, you can try `localhost:<port>` using your app's port number to connect directly. You can try it with `curl` to see what response code you get back.

Comment: I am able to connect through browser while i start the app in development mode : sudo python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 but when i curl it in a normal mode without port returns bad gateway and with port returns could not connect to host

Comment: Sorry by directly connect, I meant try curling the address of the Python server that is running the django app, not the NGINX server. You'll have to do this inside the VM that the app is running in. You should also check what happens when you try to start the app manually from within the VM. It will be more informative with regard to what error message you get back.

Comment: this is the error that found in error.log

*117 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.125.137.128, server: kwf-orion, request: "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host: "kwf-orion"

i have updated settings.py with ALLOWED_HOST=['*'] and restarted nginx but still 502 is not going away

Comment: it sounds like the python django server itself isn't starting successfully. You'll have to try and start it manually from within the VM with manage.py and see what error message you get.